# How do I override the mail system?

Tags: 8, emails

In my application, all mails aren't sent via the Drupal default mail system or SMTP. We have a third-party API which sends all emails. So, whenever the *plugin.manager.mail* service is called, the class I define in a custom module should be used.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by overriding the service defined from Drupal core.
[Altering existing services, providing dynamic services](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/services-and-dependency-injection/altering-existing-services-providing-dynamic-services) describes the code to use.

In your case, the code should be similar to the following one.

```
namespace Drupal\my_module;

use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Drupal\Core\DependencyInjection\ServiceProviderBase;

// @note: You only need Reference, if you want to change service arguments.
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

/**
 * Modifies the mail provider service.
 */
class MyModuleServiceProvider extends ServiceProviderBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function alter(ContainerBuilder $container) {
    $definition = $container->getDefinition('plugin.manager.mail');
    $definition->setClass('Drupal\MY_MODULE\MyMailProvider');
  }
}
```